# Type Safety for Testing React Navigation with React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-testing-library

NAVIGATOR

```
export type RootStackNavigator = {
   Welcome: undefined
   List: undefined
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackNavigator>()
const { Navigator, Screen } = Stack

const Navigation = () => {
   return (
      <NavigationContainer>
         <Navigator initialRouteName={'Welcome'} headerMode="none">
            <Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
            <Screen name="List" component={List} />
         </Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
   )
}
```

WELCOME SCREEN

```
interface WelcomeProps {
   navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackNavigator, 'Welcome'>
}

const Welcome = ({ navigation }: WelcomeProps) => {
   return (
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
         <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('List')} testID="touchable" style={styles.touchable}>
            etc ...
         </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </Screen>
   )
}
```

TEST

```
describe('Welcome Screen', () => {
   it('Navigates to List Screen when clicked', () => {
      const navigate = jest.fn()
      const { getByTestId } = render(<Welcome navigation={{ navigate }} />)
      fireEvent.press(getByTestId('touchable'))
      expect(navigate).toBeCalledWith('List')
   })
})
```

With all of this, I am getting this error from typescript:

```
Type '{ navigate: jest.Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to type 'StackNavigationProp<RootStackNavigator, "Welcome">'.
```

How can I solve this?

I am trying to test if I click in the screen the app renders the List Screen component.

Thank you.

PS: btw, the test is passing

Comment: I forgot to say that the test is passing anyway

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the same problem. I found a way but I'm not confident that it's the best or right way.

What I do is add only the used functions from navigation prop. I did it using `Pick` like below:

```
type PrivateScreenProps = {
  navigation: Pick<
    StackNavigationProp<MainStackRoutesType, Navigation.MainRoutes.PRIVATE>,
    'navigate'
  >;
};

export const PrivateScreen = ({ navigation }: PrivateScreenProps) => {
}
```

This will only add in the navigation, the navigate function.
So, in tests I only need to defined the navigate function inside navigation mock.

```
const navigation = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),
};

render(<PrivateScreen navigation={navigation} />);
```

If I need to use another function like `goBack`, I add it in the type:

```
type PrivateScreenProps = {
  navigation: Pick<
    StackNavigationProp<MainStackRoutesType, Navigation.MainRoutes.PRIVATE>,
    'navigate' | 'goBack'
  >;
};

// in tests
const navigation = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),
  goBack: jest.fn(),
};
```